# How to dynamically change the host in the SSH config file?

Tags: ssh, ssh-config

I'm trying to connect to a GCP instance, which changes its public IP every time it's restarted. To get the IP dynamically I use this `gcloud` command:

```
gcloud compute instances describe <vm-name> --zone europe-west --format='get(networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)'
```

Then I have this `ssh config` file:

```
Host MyHost
    ProxyCommand ~/.ssh/vm-connect
```

which points to a script `vm-connect` with the following contents

```
#!/bin/bash
get_host() {
    gcloud compute instances describe <vm-name> --zone europe-west1-b --format='get(networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)'
}

ssh minikf@$(get_host)
```

If I only run the script it connects to the VM successfully. But if I run `ssh MyHost` it gives me:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
-bash: line 1: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1: command not found
```

Answer (score 5):

I just solved this exact problem from another answer.

Here is the link to it: https://superuser.com/questions/1633430/ssh-config-with-dynamic-ip

Relevant bit:

> ProxyCommand acts as an alternative for the raw TCP connection. It doesn't replace the whole SSH connection

`%p` will substitute the port for ssh, you can add `IdentityFile` and all other [`ssh_config`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html) file options.

Here is something that may work for you, in `~/.ssh/config` add these lines

```sh
Host MyHost
    User minikf
    CheckHostIP no
    ProxyCommand bash -c "nc $(~/.ssh/vm-connect) %p"
```

Then just echo the host address from your script located in `~/.ssh/vm-connect`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
get_host() {
    gcloud compute instances describe <vm-name> --zone europe-west1-b --format='get(networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)'
}

echo get_host
```

I have added `CheckHostIP no` so that `ssh` will not throw a warning when IP address is different from the one stored in `known_hosts`. This is optional.

Comment: The echo is incorrect. Also, the function is not needed - just the raw gcloud command.
Note that on my system, I needed to provide the path to the gcloud binary. Also `StrictHostKeyChecking no` is useful to avoid the warning that the key has changed with every reboot of the GCP instance